# ReactJS - Issue about routing components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a parent component and two child components. Both components appear when I click in the menu without any problems. The problem is when I type the URI in the browser, only the parent and the first child component appears. The second child doesn't appear.

in the browser to display the
first child component
http: // localhost: 3000 / portfolio
OK. This appears without problems

I type in the browser to appear the second child component

http: // localhost: 3000 / portfolio / casas

it does not appear.

**This is the parent component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import Intro from './Intro'
import Houses from './Houses'


class PortfolioMenu extends Component {  
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div class={`wrapper2 ${portfolioClass}`}>
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
             <Route exact path='/portfolio' render={() => <Intro />} />
             <Route path='/portfolio/casas' render={() => <Houses/>}/>      
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul className={`portfolio-menu ${portfolioClass}`}>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/portfolio"><span className="bullet">•</span> introdução</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/portfolio/casas"><span className="bullet">•</span> casas</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PortfolioMenu
```

**This is the first child component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Intro extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>This is the Intro Component</div>
      </div>

    )
  }

}

export default Intro
```

**This is the second child component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Houses extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>This is the Second Component</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Houses
```

Comment: you defined the route as `/portfolio/casas` and opening `/portfolio/houses` in browser, mistake here or this is your actual code? onclick is working because `NavLink` has the correct `to` value, same as the defined route .

Comment: It was a translation mistake when I passed it to stack overflow. I will edit the question.

Comment: question edited

Comment: is this the complete code? there seems to be missing code for you Route component with the path `/portfolio/casas`

Comment: <Route exact path='/portfolio/casas' render={() => <Houses/>}/>             
correct you route code first

Comment: I had deleted that part of the code without realizing it. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: can you make sure, you have a single Router component in your code?

Comment: Yes. The parent component is the only component for routing.

Comment: you have use `exact` in multiple Route and `exact` path need to be `"/"`

Comment: @binodstha7 I have edited based in your suggestion ant the issue continues happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there shouldn't be multiple exact path in router and exact path should be root path i think that is `exact path="/"`.

```html
<Router>
          <div class={`wrapper2 ${portfolioClass}`}>
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
             <Route exact path='/' component={Intro} />
             <Route path='/portfolio/casas' component={Houses}/>      
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul className={`portfolio-menu ${portfolioClass}`}>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/"><span className="bullet">•</span> introdução</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/portfolio/casas"><span className="bullet">•</span> casas</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </Router>
```